# Crouton,Chromebook HP 14,Ubuntu 12.04 and a USB printer possible?

Tags: 12.04, wine, printing, libreoffice, chromebook

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my wife's HP 14 Chromebook via Crouton method.
The main reason was Libre Office, which she likes a lot more than the "Microsoft Word Online" option in Chrome OS. Anyways, I have everything working, but was curious if there is a way to hook up her HP printer and have it recognized via USB by the Ubuntu interface. Her printer is not WiFi or cloud enabled. It's simply USB. Otherwise it's a perfectly good working printer. Will installing Common Unix Printing System make this work for me? On blind faith, I plugged in the printer to the chromebook running Ubuntu environment, but when I clicked print, I got the error asking for localhost.

Because Chromebook is only cloudprint, I'm thinking this is a Hardware issue, not software. So that's why I'm hesitant to install anything that could be uneccessary.

Or is it possible WINE would be a solution?

Also>for reference in installing Ubuntu environment on Chromebook HP 14 : [InstallUbuntuOnChROMEBOOK](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/03/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-minecraft-on.html)

Edit: Here's a screenshot of what I'm looking at when opening "Printer" in hardware settings.
 [image: screenshot printer]

And then when I hit the "Connect" button:

[image]

And then finally, when I click "Connect" on second prompt, I get:

```
CUPS server error: There was an error during the CUPS operation."failed to connect to server"
```

Comment: "Will installing Common Unix Printing System" ? " I got the CUPS error asking" I would assume CUPS -IS- installed? You need to install the printer by going to "printers" and add it. USB printers tend to work after having it search for it.

Comment: I tried that first, and it was not recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working solution [in the crouton wiki](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Printing):

> 1. Install cups and related packages: `sudo apt-get install cups system-config-printer-gnome`
>      To get a working `lpr` command, also install `cups-bsd`. You'll also want to install `hplip` if you're using an HP printer. Get the latest hplip package and make from http://hplipopensource.com/. There maybe other packages necessary for other printers, please add them here.
> 2. Add yourself to the lpadmin group: `sudo adduser <username> lpadmin`
> 3. init scripts don't work right in crouton so we need to start cups somehow. One way is to edit `/etc/rc.local` and add: `/usr/sbin/cupsd`
> 4. If you want to connect to remote CUPS servers, install `cups-browsed`, put your configuration into `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf`, and in `/etc/rc.local` add: `/usr/sbin/cups-browsed` &
> 5. Finally, log out of your crouton and back in. You should now be able use Printer Settings to configure your printer."

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer that solved the question as accepted, even if it is your own. There is nothing bad about that and you are even encouraged to post Q&A-style if it helps the site. :)