# Installing HP Deskjet on Chromebook using Ubuntu?

Tags: printing, hp, scanner, chromebook

I have an HP Chromebook 14 and have bought an HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 1515 which cannot be installed on Chrome OS. Can I use Ubuntu to install the printer on my Chromebook?

Comment: Please clarify, do you intend to install Ubuntu on the Chromebook itself or another computer? Perhaps by using the widely advertized crouton solution?

Answer (score 0):

Actually , yes you can do this. It will take some set-up, but it is possible. I've done this to my own Hp 14 Chromebook. I should say that I'm not particularly using the HP deskjet 1515, but I'm using the HP photosmart 5180. Instead of typing out the entire process, I will enter links for you in chronological order of doing this.

1. [Installing Ubuntu on Chromebook via CROUTON method.](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/03/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-minecraft-on.html) (Nevermind the Minecraft steps at end.
2. [A little extra information/Pay attention to Unity,Crouton etc.](http://voltron00x.com/2014/04/06/chromebooks-part-3-beyond-chrome-os-ubuntu-and-crouton/)
3. [GitHub, CUPS,CROUTON set-up with HP](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Printing)
4. [You'll need to install Gedit if your moving on to step 5 with](http://www.lucidlynx.com/how-to-use-gedit-in-ubuntu-to-work-with-files/)
5. A [little further for setting up CUPS start-up. Look at Bweinel's answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2174219)

These are the links I have saved from my set-up a few months ago. Hope this helps you out. And here's a [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523576/crouton-chromebook-hp-14-ubuntu-12-04-and-a-usb-printer-possible?rq=1) to my own Askubuntu question, from when I was having trouble getting the printer to connect.

Comment: That has nothing to do with his question at all. He is asking how to install HIS PRINTER on Chrome OS on his Chromebook and if he can somehow use another PC that has Ubuntu to help him do that. His question has nothing to do with Ubuntu running on a Chromebook.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste You are the first one stating something about using another computer in this question. But we can ask the OP herself/himself for clarification instead of patronizing.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. A computer running Ubuntu won't be able to install and set up a printer on a different computer, especially not one that uses a different operating system. If Chrome OS doesn't support your printer, blame Google's developers.

Comment: I'm sure the OP meant using the printer from within Ubuntu on the Chromebook.

Comment: What? You can't have Ubuntu on a Chromebook! Chromebooks are locked to Chrome OS unless you use an unofficial hack that can brick your system and void your warranty. You don't know what you're talking about!

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/poking-around-your-chrome-os-device https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton Anything else you want to tell us?

Comment: Yeah, that https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton is unofficial and voids your warranty and is not developed by anyone at the Chromium Project and that Ubuntu would probably have hardware compatibility problems anyway. Notice how in the question that he said he is having problems installing his printer on Chrome OS and not Ubuntu, and his question ends with him asking if he can use a separate Ubuntu machine to install the printer in Chrome OS on his Chromebook, so running Ubuntu on Chromebooks is unrelated to his question anyway.

Comment: *"Can I use Ubuntu to install the printer on my Chromebook?"* Yes you can by putting you Chromebook in developer mode and install Ubuntu in a chroot using crouton, which is completely reversible and doesn't void your warranty in any way. Are you sure we are talking about the same question? Have you even understood how chroot or LXC works? Have you tried installing crouton on a Chromebook yourself? I can say that I did. I'm not very convinced that this solution is a proper way to experience Ubuntu, but if you need some software on your Chromebook to talk to your printer, then go for it!

Comment: I suppose so. Warranties vary by manufacturer, so it's always good to read it, just to be safe. I see now. He wanted to put Ubuntu on his Chromebook. And before you say you were right and make me admit I'm a moron, I should point out that nowhere in the question does he say what computer Ubuntu will be runnibg on. He asks if he can use Ubuntu, but Ubuntu is an OS, not a computer. I misunderstood the question. You're probably right (but that does not mean I'm wrong).